# How to stub in Rails development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a reliable way to dynamically stub certain methods in my development environment. One example use case is when I need to do development that normally requires access to the Facebook Graph APIs but I don't have Internet access. I'd like to be able to stub the calls to fb_graph methods so it looks as if I'm authenticated and have profile data. Ideally I could turn the stubs on or off with a minor config change.

Any ideas? I'm assuming something like mocha can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VCR gem which will record the results of an initial HTTP request into a yml file and then use the contents of that yml file on subsequent http requests. It can then be configured to ignore the VCR logic and always make HTTP requests, if so desired:

https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr

Answer (score 1):

Mocha can certainly do it. But it feels a bit strange.

You could also do something like dependency injection.

For instance:

```
class User < AR::Base

  def find_friends
    Facebook.find_friends(facebook_id)
  end

end

class Facebook

  def self.find_friends(id)
    # connect to Facebook here
  end

end

class FakeFacebook

  def self.find_friends(id)
    # a fake implementation here
  end

end
```

And inside an initializer:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  User::Facebook = FakeFacebook
end
```